# Philosophy of sankhya

Tags: sankhya

If Purusa and Prakiti are two completely independent realities, then no relation between the two is possible. How does sankara criticise sankhya?

Comment: It would help if you can refer to the exact criticism and the text.

Comment: unclear what you are asking. you have partially answered your own question in the question....